# Why is my script not creating a new document on form submit?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```js
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var test1 = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  
  var test2 = itemResponses[1].getResponse();

  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("114DNaUycHvCfia13cPf_ht4366s5mVU5eExsEGi9aQE");
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1zUrELKuybVfG2O6Gw0FkgT1ZET0XkBkw");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(test1, templateFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{TEST 1}}", test1);
  if(test2 == "None") {
    var string = body.findText("{{TEST 2}}");
    var startOffset = string.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = string.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    string.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset, endOffset);
  }
  else {
    body.replaceText("{{TEST 2}}", test2);
  }

  doc.saveAndClose();

  
}
```

Hey all I have reached to in here regarding requesting how to create a string to clear a specific field of text if a a google form has been answered in a specific way. However this script is now no longer creating a new doc on form submit. Is there any reasons why this is not working and will the script clear the text if the "none" option is selected?

Comment: Why are you asking us? You have the code and you have a debugger, go forth and debug.

Comment: I tried to replicate your code and it is working just fine. Have you tried checking the Executions tab of your Apps Script? You can verify there whether your script fails or not. It also has logs which you can use to trace the cause of the error.

Comment: Hey so I have looked through the executions tab and its coming up as failed where the error is " TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined" @Nikko J. 

Apologies Im not familiar in any form of script writing and had learnt the basis of this script from a youtube tutorial where the rest has been support through here

Comment: @ManrajSidhu - Is your form created using Google Sheets (Insert -> Form)? How did you set up your installable trigger? Could you provide a screenshot of it? (You can find the installable trigger on the Triggers tab of your script). Also, please do share the Sheet or Form you are using for this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to create on form submit event:

1. By creating installable trigger from a script created in Google Sheets
2. By creating installable trigger from a script created in Google Forms

When you create a form using Google Sheets (**Insert -> Form**) and create an Installable Trigger in Apps Script, your trigger will look like this:

[image]

And this is the event object the trigger will return: [Google Sheets Form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

While when you create a script directly to Google Forms and create an Installable Trigger there, the trigger will look like this:

[image]

And this is the event object the trigger will return: [Google Forms Form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

When you compare the form submit event object of those two, only Google Forms has the `response` object.

If the event source of your trigger is `From Spreadsheet` and you use the `response.getItemResponses()`, this will return a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined`  since the object `response` is not available in the Google Sheets form submit object.

[image]

To fix the issue, use the Google Sheets form submit object instead:

Try this:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var test1 = e.values[1];  
  var test2 = e.values[2];
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("template file id");
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("template folder id");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(test1, templateFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{TEST 1}}", test1);
  if(test2 == "None") {
    var string = body.findText("{{TEST 2}}");
    var startOffset = string.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = string.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    string.getElement().asText().deleteText(startOffset, endOffset);
  }
  else {
    body.replaceText("{{TEST 2}}", test2);
  }
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

**Example Response:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]